# How do you handle requests in Pyodide / Stlite?

Tags: python, python-requests, streamlit, pyodide

From what I've read so far Pyodide does not work with requests library. Usage of pyodide.http.pyfetch is recommended. But as it is async it really trips me and I can't figure it out (pyodide.http.open_url won't work as I'm sending get request to an api and I need to add some headers).

So the question is - how do make a request to an api and stop the further execution of a function until coroutine finishes?

I'm trying to get the data from the API, and use it to create an object. In regular Streamlit it works flawlessly.

```
class FabmanData:
    LINKS: Final = {
        "members": "members?orderBy=name&order=asc",
        "resource": "resources?orderBy=name&order=asc",
        "bookings": "bookings?order=desc&limit=50&summary=false",
    }

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.members: pd.DataFrame = self.get_data("members")[
            ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "memberNumber"]
        ]
        self.resources: pd.DataFrame = self.get_data("resource")[
            ["id", "name", "state"]
        ]
        self.latest_bookings: pd.DataFrame = self.get_data("bookings")[
            ["id", "resource", "fromDateTime", "untilDateTime", "member"]
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(category) -> pd.DataFrame:
        url = f"{BASEURL}{FabmanData.LINKS[category]}"
        return pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url=url, headers=HEADERS).json())

    def get_resources_dict(self):
        return {
            resource: resource_id
            for resource, resource_id in zip(
                self.resources["name"], self.resources["id"]
            )
        }
```

But I can't figure it out with pyfetch . I get `TypeError: coroutine object is not subscriptable` . Thus I assume that get_data method returns coroutine and I don't know what to do to make it return a value.
Currently it looks like this:

```
    @staticmethod
    async def get_data(category) -> pd.DataFrame:
        url = f"{BASEURL}{FabmanData.LINKS[category]}"
        response = await pyodide.http.pyfetch(url=url, headers=HEADERS)
        await asyncio.wait_for(response, timeout=10)
        data = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
        return data
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [pyodide-http](https://github.com/koenvo/pyodide-http) package. It monkey-patches `requests` and `urllib` to work in a (mostly) browser-friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

`pyodide.http.pyfetch` is the solution as you wrote.

You have to use it with `await` as [the Pyodide document says](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#how-can-i-load-external-files-in-pyodide) because it's an async function and it returns a coroutine object that must be `await`ed to get the actual result. Note that the awaited result is a [`FetchResponse`](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api/http.html#pyodide.http.FetchResponse) object, so you also have to use its method such as `.string()` or `.bytes()` to get the actual content (See [the doc](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api/http.html)).
Here is an example:

```py
from pyodide.http import pyfetch

url = "https://example.com/some_file"
res = await pyfetch(url)
data = await res.bytes()
```

stlite [allows to use `await` at the top level](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite#top-level-await), so you can write code like above.

Also, as usual, you can use `pyodide.http.pyfetch` in an async function with `await`. In that case, you would `await` the outer async function with a top level await like this:

```py
from pyodide.http import pyfetch

async def main():
    url = "https://example.com/some_file"
    res = await pyfetch(url)
    data = await res.bytes()

await main()
```

[This section of stlite's README](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite#top-level-await) explains these things with the example of `pyfetch`.